# Задача 1/0!+1/1!+1/2!+

Tags: python

По данному натуральному числу N найдите сумму чисел 1+1/1!+1/2!+1/3!+...+1/N!. Количество действий должно быть пропорционально N.

Входные данные 
Задано единственное число N

Выходные данные
Необходимо вывести  результат вычисления в виде действительного числа c точностью до 5 знаков после запятой.

В 1 из 9 тестов пишет превышено максимальное время работы. Как исправить?

```
N = int(input())

sum = 1
f = 1
for g in range(1, N + 1):
    f *= g
    sum += 1 / f

print(sum)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Достаточно двух действий на каждой итерции.

```
sum = 1
f = 1
for g in range(1, N + 1):
    f = f / g
    sum += f
```

Comment: IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: И там же нужен факториал, а не простое деление

Comment: @Пельмень Я не понял - я должен Вам правильно отступы расставить? Про факториал - возьмите лист бумаги и карандаш и выполните действия вручную для какого-нибудь `N`.

Comment: Простите, ошибся, все правильно, 100 баллов дали, спасибо

Comment: @Пельмень На здоровье. Успехов!

Answer (score 2):

Используя `reduce` и `factorial`:

```py
from functools import reduce
from math import factorial

N = int(input())
sum = reduce(lambda x, y: x + 1/factorial(y), range(1, N+1)) + 1
print(sum)
```

или в цикле

```py
p = 1
res = 1
N = int(input())
for i in range(N, 0, -1):
    p *= i
    res += p
res /= p
print(res)
```